# Nested where cases in SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sample @start DATE,@end DATE,@type VARCHAR(5)
AS
    SELECT o.O_Id,
           o.Sale_Price,
           o.Private_Band,
           c.Date_of_Purchase,
           c.Date_Redeemed,
           c.Type,
           c.Points_Issued,
           o.Date_of_Purchase
    FROM Order_Details o,
         Transaction_Historys c
    WHERE CASE
               WHEN o.Date_of_Purchase BETWEEN @start AND @end
                AND (c.Type = @type) THEN 1
               WHEN c.Type = @type THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END = 1
GO
EXECUTE dbo.sample @type=NULL,@start='2012-03-01',@end='2012-03-30'
GO
```

When I test with `@type=null` I don't get data. I need to handle below 2 cases where condition

```
INput CASE1=wen @type is NULL-> WHERE c.Date_Redeemed BETWEEN @Start AND @End-- this should execute
If CASE2=wen @start,@end is NULL->WHERE c.Type=@type-- this should execute
```

Comment: don't do this; use dedicated predicates straight in the where. you cannot use `=` to compare NULL with anything, even another NULL; the result will always eventually behave like FALSE. use `IS NULL` to check for nulls

Comment: Im new to this can you share the sample modification so i can get over it

Comment: Is it intentional that you have a `CROSS JOIN` here? Even if you do, it's 2020; it's long past time you start using the 1992 ANSI-JOIN syntax: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite:

```
WHERE
   o.Date_of_Purchase BETWEEN @start AND @end OR
   c.Type = @type OR
   (@type IS NULL and @start is null)
```

- Set type as null and start/end as not null to do date search
- Set start/end as null and type as not null to do type search
- Set type and start as null to return all records. If you want NO RECORDS, remove the `OR  (@type IS NULL and @start is null)`

As I commented, only `IS NULL` can be used to return true when working with nulls. If @start is null then `o.Date_of_Purchase BETWEEN @start AND @end` will always be false so @type will be used instead. Same for @type is null, then @start/@end will be used. If both are null, then first two conditions always false, so you just need to decide what to do if both are null. You might also want a different behavior for if all data are provided, in which case you can look at being explicit:

```
WHERE
   (c.Type = @type AND o.Date_of_Purchase BETWEEN @start AND @end) OR
   (@start IS NULL AND c.Type = @type) OR
   (@type IS NULL and o.Date_of_Purchase BETWEEN @start AND @end) OR
   (@start IS NULL AND @type IS NULL)
```

In this,

- if both are provided, only rows where type and date match are returned,
- if type is not provided, date is used,
- if date not provided type is used and
- if nothing provided all rows return. To make no rows return, remove the last predicate

Comment: I want to handle the cases dynamically based on input from the end user how to make three cases handle

Comment: CASE3=o.Market_class=var class
CASE4=o.Order_value BETWEEN var price1 AND  var price2 I wanted to handle this cases to with above cases like combination if either is null of 4 cases it shuld handle dynamicaly its like permutation/combination.I culdnt able to handle to rewite with this3,4 case with abv 2,can u gve the idea

Comment: Honestly, the more things you put in the worse performance can end up. To return data efficiently the db has to plan how to execute the query. If the SQL mentions every column in the table it might end up picking a really bad strategy and then using it every time is sees the query. If you're offering some kind of dynamic search to your user where they write in some fields and not others you'd be better off using string concatenation to build a parametrized where clause based off what they entered , dynamically adding parameter values and running the query

Comment: Can you give some ref links for string conct to build parametrized where clause,and can you chnage the above code which u have given into parametrized where clause so i cn have idea what you are saying exactly

Comment: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/ - please ask a new question linking to this one